# Vuetify loader which depends on API response

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I made a login form and button with preloader:

```
<v-btn @click="login" :loading="loading4" :disabled="loading4"
       @click.native="loader = 'loading4'">
  {{ $t('forms.labels.loginBtn') }}           
  <span slot="loader" class="btn-loader">
    <v-icon light>cached</v-icon>
  </span>
</v-btn>
```

I want to show btn preloader when api response is 'pending'.
I fetch api status from computed:

```
...mapGetters({
  loginStatus: 'auth/authStatus'
}),
```

In Vuetify docs I found only solution with setTimeout and I don't know how to customize it to my api response:

```
watch: {
  loader () {
    const l = this.loader
    this[l] = !this[l]

    setTimeout(() => (this[l] = false), 3000)

    this.loader = null
  }
}
```

My store:

```
const state = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('user-token'),
  status: null
}
```

I want to show preloader only when state status is 'loading'. I'm changing state using mutation.

How to do this and what `this[l]` means?
Thanks.

Comment: Your code snippet is lacking. Please make it more detailed like including the whole component code.

Comment: You can also add a loading attribute to the auth state, and just listen on that.

Comment: I have a status attribute in my state ( I am changing it using mutation). But I don't know how to show preloader depend on state.

Answer (score 3):

Using brackets or `[` and `]` is just an another way for [accessing properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) in your Javascript object aside from the dot or `.` operator.

The brackets is usually used for accessing properties dynamically.

For example, the most common way to access an object property is like this:

```
this.loading4 = true;
```

But, you can also do it like this if you want to:

```
this['loading4'] = true;
```

and you can also supply a variable instead of a string literal:

```
const l = 'loading4';
this[l] = true;
```

It's basically like you are treating your `object` like a `multi-dimensional array` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using `loading` as a state in your Vuex module without using watch hook just like *@Jeremy Walters* suggested.

**Vuex**

```
state: {
    loading: false
},

getters: {
   isLoading(state) {
     return state.loading
},

mutations: {
  loginSuccess(state, payload) {
     state.loading = false    //ends the loader
     ...
  },
  loginFailed(state, payload) {
     state.loading = false    //ends the loader
     ...
  },
},

actions: {
    login({state,commit},credentials) {

         state.loading = true    //starts the loader

         axios.post('/api/auth/login', credentials)
         .then((response) => {
             commit("loginSuccess", response.data)
         })
         .catch((error) => {
             commit("loginFailed", error.response.data)
         })
}
```

Then in your component

**HTML**

```
 <v-btn @click="login" :loading="isLoading" :disabled="isLoading">
    {{ $t('forms.labels.loginBtn') }}           
    <span slot="loader" class="btn-loader">
       <v-icon light>cached</v-icon>
    </span>
 </v-btn>
```

**JS**

```
...mapGetters({
    'isLoading'
})
```

Regarding the explanation for the `this[l]`, it was already explained nicely by the answer below.